# iOS UITest : How to find UITableViewCell's AccessoryView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, accessoryview, uitest

Hello I'm learning `UITests` now

I have a question

how can detect accessoryView's tap on the `tableViewCell`?? in UITest

below is my `tableViewCell`

[image]

I want detect detail closure accesorry view's tap

like this

`app.tables.cells.buttons["FTCellAccesoryIdentifier"].tap()`

but accesorry is a subclass of `UIView`

so i allocate accisibility identifier key in `cellForRows` function

`cell.accessoryView?.accessibilityIdentifier ="FTCellAccesoryIdentifier"`

and my test function is

i try

```
app.tables.cells.elementBoundByIndex(lastCellIndex).otherElements.elementMatchingType(.Any, identifier: "FTCellAccesoryIdentifier").tap()
```

but not work

is possible to tap cell's accesoryView in UITests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## TL;DR

Regarding...

> is possible to tap cell's accesoryView in UITests?

... Yes.
But you have to use the **default accessibility identifier** for that.
For example, for a cell like this one:

[image]

Tapping the **Detail Disclosure** button during a UI test ("*More Info*" is the key here):

```
XCUIApplication().tables.buttons["More Info, Title"].tap()
```

Tapping **the cell itself** during a UI test:

```
XCUIApplication().tables.staticTexts["Title"].tap()
```

### Long story:

There is no way to change the default accessibility identifier of the Detail Disclosure. [From Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH102-SW3):

> Note: If your table cells contain any of the standard table-view elements, such as the disclosure indicator, detail disclosure button,
>   or delete control, you do not have to do anything to make these
>   elements accessible. If, however, your table cells include other types
>   of controls, such as a switch or a slider, you need to make sure that
>   these elements are appropriately accessible.

At the time you try to set the accessibility identifier/label of the Detail Disclosure in `cellForRow`, `cell.accessoryView` is nil. Why? Again, from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html):

**accessoryView**

**Discussion**

> If the value of this property is not nil, the UITableViewCell class
>   uses the given view for the accessory view in the table view’s normal
>   (default) state; it ignores the value of the accessoryType property.
>   The provided accessory view can be a framework-provided control or
>   label or a custom view. The accessory view appears in the the right
>   side of the cell.

The accessory view will be nil until you define them. :/

You would need to provide your "own" Detail Disclosure (e.g.: a customized *UIView*) if you really want to set a custom identifier for it. For example (to illustrate):

```
cell.accessoryView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20))
cell.accessoryView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
cell.accessoryView?.accessibilityIdentifier = "FTCellAccesoryIdentifier"
```

Comment: Thank you for your detail answer :) I apply your code XCUIApplication().tables.buttons["More Info, Title"].tap() by using predicate and find specific cell using elementBoundByIndex()

Answer (score 1):

You should use `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` delegate method to handle click on `accessoryView`.

Then by `indexPath` parameter of method you can know which cell it is!

Hope this will help :)

Comment: thank you for your answer :) but this is not solution I want to find how can tap accessoryView in XCTestCase (UITest) by programingly